# Extracting a project as a separate project from the Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I have a solution that contains multiple projects.

I would like to extract one project from a solution to create a new, separate solution, that would only contain this one project.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: new solution - > add existing project, that should work; however, if the project had dependencies on the other projects in the solution, there could be ALOT of build errors.....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If by "Extract", you mean "Duplicate" your project and start a new solution with this project, here is what you can do:

1. Create a new solution in Visual Studio
2. Copy your Project folder in the root of the new solution
3. Right click on the solution => *Add existing Project* and select
   the project file (*.csproj in this case)

Comment: Why do you have to copy both the project folder and the *.csproj over? Does the project folder not already contain the *.csproj file? What is the effect of adding it to the solution on top of having copied it manually?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The question was about creating a new solution starting from an already existing project located in another solution. Yes, the project folder contains the project file.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the project folder into separate folder, open the .csproj file, press `CTRL + S`, it will open the save dialog and you will save the `.sln` file. That is it.

Comment: Pressing `CTRL + S` didn't work for me in VS 2022. I used `CTRL + SHIFT + S` or **Save All**

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any project, then **Exclude from Project**. The excluded files  will be in the project folder. Move those files to another folder, in the way you want it. Then you can create and add those files in new project by **Add existing item**

Comment: Sounds like the opposite..?

Comment: sorry, its exclude from project, so that the files will be in the project folder but not in the solution. we can add those files in new project @TaW